# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, heroku, sqlite3-python

I'm developing a simple app using Django. I am done with the development and I'm trying to push to Heroku server. I get this error if I try to create a superuser

```
You have 21 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, journpys, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
Traceback (most recent call last):`File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute`
return super().execute(query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

I need help in fixing this error. Thanks.

All migrations have been done locally and using the Heroku run python manage.py migrate command with no issues.  I have also looked at some articles on solutions to this error but none seemed to work.

**Update**: *I resolved this by switching to PostgreSQL. This has been finally resolved.*

Answer (score 0):

u need to Update Database Configuration in settings.py (at the bottom of the file) and after that excute this commant `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

checkout this link( read comments in this article as well ): [enter link description here](https://www.codementor.io/@jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4)

Comment: I followed the directives from the link but still got this exception '_django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user_'

Comment: you can try this as well, delete the **sqllite3** file and delete all of the files inside all of the migrations folders except ```__init__.py```, then run the ```makemigrations``` and ```migrate``` command again and then follow the instruction from the link again

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried all these but they did not work. I fixed it by switching to Postgres.